# Jupyter notebook cannot import package geopy

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, geopy

Working in a Jupyter notebook, installed the package `geopy` and restart kernel.

```
import geopy
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-99b9d2081153> in <module>
----> 1 import geopy

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopy
```

I can confirm `geopy` is istalled (from within Jupyter notebook) by running:

```
!pip install  geopy
Requirement already satisfied: geopy in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: geographiclib<2,>=1.49 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from geopy) (1.50)
```

If it may helps:

```
!python -V
Python 3.8.3

!which python
/home/kabir/Desktop/dataset/venv/bin/python
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplication of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54975897/unable-to-import-geopy-into-jupyter-even-after-piop-installation

Comment: Make sure jupyter uses the same python executable as reported by the `which` command. It looks like they are different in your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install it with the specific pip what's associated with your current Python kernel which is running inside Jupyter:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m  pip install geopy
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command in your default command line and in Jupyter notebook.

```
which python
```

The path should match the one that you have in Jupyter notebook, if it doesn't than this is your issue.